# Was Shakespeare a member of the lower classes?

Tags: history

Am I correct to assume there is a feud between academics considering Shakespeare's social origins? I understand that he was probably born as a member of the working classes (or even the Elizabethan underclass), but his skill might suggest something equivalent to what is portrayed in the film Anonymous, where Shakespeare was a noble who wrote under the name of a commoner. What is the state of this debate? What sources could I read that summarize it?

Comment: As i understand it, nobody is 100% certain who wrote the things we attribute to shakespeare.

Comment: What does this question have to do with philosophy? It's a fine question but it is off topic for this site. Try [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have moved it there, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Was Shakespeare a member of the lower classes?

For sure, not a noble.

You can see : Lois Potter, [The Life of William Shakespeare : A Critical Biography (Blackwell, 2012)](https://books.google.it/books?id=V0Udd61zN4cC&printsec=frontcover), page 2 and 3 :

> John Shakespeare [(William’s father) was] chamberlain or acting chamberlain of Stratford-upon-Avon from 1561 to 1565, [he] had been heavily involved with maintenance and improvement of Corporation buildings.
>
> Mary Shakespeare [born Mary Arden] family name derived from the forest of Arden, which contains the villages in which all the pre-1500 Shakespeares lived.